# Populate a combo from a json hash but in sorted order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, combobox

I have a JSON hash and I populate a combo box as follows:

```
$.each(json_hash, function(key, value) {   
    $("#select").append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>");
});
```

It works fine but the problem is that it does not show the data in sorted order.
What is the easiest way I can populate the combo placing the data in sorted order according to value?

Answer (score 0):

Add this before your code

```
json_hast.sort(function(a,b) { return a.value - b.value } );
```

Comment: I get: `Object has no method sort`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'sort'`

Comment: Sorry, to use sort method json object should be converted to array     `var json_array = $.map(_elements, function (item, index) {
                return [[item.key, item.value]];
            });` Then use `json_array.sort(function(a,b) { return a.value - b.value } );`

Comment: But how do I populate the combo then?